# Is there a way to trustworthily say that certain phone number is a Skype number?

Tags: skype, phone

I was given a phone number. I suspect that a person doesn't directly own this number and/or isn't present in the country where this number has been registered (bound by country code), so I want to know if Skype issued this number. Is there a tool or, more generally, a way to tell that for certain?

Comment: Without the telephone number it is impossible to answer. Each country has its own regulators who allocate numbers to providers ...

Answer (score 1):

I won't exactly answer your question.
First, phone regulation depends on countries.
For the case of France, and probably Germany, operators are assigned block of numbers, which they use how they want. And the numbers I have in France cannot be distinguished, especially that you can "port" a number from another operator.

There is also much more to the picture than just Skype. I myself have phone numbers in various countries, that I can pick up from pretty much anywhere in the world (this is Voice Over IP, in my case, SIP).

Comment: To elaborate, the above is all true, and the answer to the question is "No". While Skype does not support inbound number porting, it does support outbound porting so any number that was originally a Skype number could be transferred to another operator. You can theoretically tell if Skype originally *issued* the number by checking against all possible Skype numbers but that does not guarantee the number is *still* a Skype number.

Comment: An answer that specifically says "I won't exactly answer your question" isn't really that helpful.